# how can i make a list for the plots on a cob web

Tags: plotting, demonstrations

This work book is perfect but it has no list of the plots it makes. Is there a way to copy the coordinates of the plots and paste them?

[link to cob web](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TimeSeriesAndCobwebsForArbitraryRecursiveMapsOnTheUnitInterv/)

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply download the code and run it yourself?  And who calls this a "cob web"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Never heard it in this context but cobweb is a pretty common name for a spider's web (normally one that no longer has a spider living in it), just in case you weren't aware 

Comment: Oh of *course* I know what cob webs and spider's webs are.  Of *course*.  But the mathematical figures are not cob webs... not at all.  You should not use terms that seem as if they are standard terminology when they are not; you should use standard terminology.  Otherwise, you're just sowing confusion.  But why not just copy the code and be done with all of this anyway??

Comment: @David, "cobweb diagrams"/"cobweb plots" are the term of art used in some references (e.g. [this](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=4RWUtBO_FSkC&pg=PA85) and [this](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=vpYmj7ohofsC&pg=PA142), tho I think Robert Devaney is the one who originally came up with the term), but perhaps not in the references you are accustomed to. ;)

Comment: OK.  I learned something.  Thanks.